# cannot convert int to int[] and operator is undefined for types int[], int []

Tags: java

I am having issues printing out my array  as  my loops will not print due to it saying cannot convert int to int[]. and my addition and multiplication wont concatenate as it says the operator "+" and "*" are undefined for types int[],int[]

If someone could help me figure out why these issues are happening as I though I had it written correctly. IM not very knowledgeable with arrays so any information would be greatly appreciated

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Matrix {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter number of rows");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int row = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter number of columns");
        int column = sc.nextInt();
        
        int[][] a1 = new int[row][column];
        int[][] a2 = new int[row][column];
        
        for(int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < column; c++) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Enter first [%d][%d] integer",r,c));


                a1[r]= sc.nextInt();    //cannot convert int to int[]


            }
        }
        
        for(int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < column; c++) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Enter first [%d][%d] integer",r,c));


                a2[r]= sc.nextInt();    cannot convert int to int[]


            }
        }

        System.out.println("First Matrix: ");
        PrintArray(a1);
        System.out.println("First Matrix: ");
        PrintArray(a2);
        
        add(a1,a2);
        multiply(a1,a2);
        
        
        }
    
    public static void add(int[][] a1,int[][] a2) {
        int row = a1.length;
        int column = a1[0].length;
        int[][] add = new int [row][column];
        
        for(int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < column; c++) {


                add[r] = (a1[r] + a2[r]); // operator "+" is undefined for types int[],int[]


            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of added arrays: "+ add);
    }
    
    public static void multiply(int[][] a1,int[][] a2) {
        int row = a1.length;
        int column = a1[0].length;
        int[][] add = new int [row][column];
        
        for(int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < column; c++) {


                add[r] = (a1[r] * a2[r]); // operator "*" is undefined for types int[],int[]


            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of added arrays: "+ add);
    }
    
    public static void PrintArray(int[][] matrix) {
        for(int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++ ) {
            for(int c = 0; c <matrix[0].length; c++) {
                System.out.println(matrix[r] + "\t" );
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `a1[r]` ---> `a1[r][c]`. Similar for `a2` and `add`, and perhaps others I've missed.

Comment: That fixed the ones for my loops however, for the addition and multiplication its still showing the operators are undefined and now cannot convert int to int[] along with it

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `a1` and `a2` are 2 dimensional arrays.

Your for loop iteration is fine, but `a1[r]` is an `int[]` and not `int`.

You are trying to assign an integer value to an array, so you are getting a cannot convert error.

```java
a1[r]= sc.nextInt();
```

Should be changed to:

```java
a1[r][c] = sc.nextInt();
```

Similarly addition and multiplication are only available for the primitive type or wrappers but not on arrays.

```java
add[r] = (a1[r] + a2[r]);
```

Has to be changed to:

```java
add[r][c] = (a1[r][c] + a2[r][c]);
```

And

```java
add[r] = (a1[r] * a2[r]);
```

Has to be changed to:

```
add[r][c] = (a1[r][c] * a2[r][c]);
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that! I was so confused as to what was wrong. Would there be a reason as to why when I run this, it prints out the address rather than the number?

Comment: for example: Sum of added arrays: [[I@55f96302
Sum of added arrays: [[I@3d4eac69

Comment: @WesleyHarrison Use `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(add))`. Otherwise, it will just print of the address of the array not the contents like you said.

Comment: Okay once doing that it says that its not applicable for the target (void), which I would imagine is what my return type is for both the add and multiply methods.

Comment: I tried doing that as well and the issue still remains. It does give me the option to change it back to toString() but its just a back and forth kinda thing. once you change it to that it gives the option to change back to deepToString. but also the other option is that the return type can be changed to Object[] but I dont think thats what i want to do?

Comment: Okay I got it, I changed the void to Object[] and returned multiply and add. It still prints the address but it does give me answers as well.

Answer (score 2):

you have to put this code  then it works

your code is fine you just forgot to put an array with two dimensions a[r][c]

```
import java.util.*;

public class Matrix {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter number of rows");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int row = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter number of columns");
    int column = sc.nextInt();
    
    int[][] a1 = new int[row][column];
    int[][] a2 = new int[row][column];
    
    for(int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < column; c++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Enter first [%d][%d] integer",r,c));


            a1[r][c]= sc.nextInt();    // 2 dimensions a1[r] is not fine


        }
    }
    
    for(int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < column; c++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Enter first [%d][%d] integer",r,c));


            a2[r][c]= sc.nextInt();    // 2 dimensions a2[r] is not fine


        }
    }

    System.out.println("First Matrix: ");
    PrintArray(a1);
    System.out.println("First Matrix: ");
    PrintArray(a2);
    
    add(a1,a2);
    multiply(a1,a2);
    
    
    }

public static void add(int[][] a1,int[][] a2) {
    int row = a1.length;
    int column = a1[0].length;
    int[][] add = new int [row][column];
    
    for(int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < column; c++) {


            add[r][c] = (a1[r][c] + a2[r][c]); // operator "+" is undefined for types int[],int[]


        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of added arrays: "+ add);
}

public static void multiply(int[][] a1,int[][] a2) {
    int row = a1.length;
    int column = a1[0].length;
    int[][] add = new int [row][column];
    
    for(int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < column; c++) {


            add[r][c] = (a1[r][c] * a2[r][c]); // operator "*" is undefined for types int[],int[]


        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of added arrays: "+ add);
}

public static void PrintArray(int[][] matrix) {
    for(int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++ ) {
        for(int c = 0; c <matrix[0].length; c++) {
            System.out.println(matrix[r] + "\t" );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

your output for 2 row 2 column for example

```
Please enter number of rows
2
Please enter number of columns
2
Enter first [0][0] integer
12
Enter first [0][1] integer
36
Enter first [1][0] integer
25
Enter first [1][1] integer
23
```